# What is the most efficient way to add a column to a pandas dataframe with concatenated values from the n rows around each row?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

Suppose I have a Pandas dataframe with language data such that each row is one word token from a text and each column contains one piece of information about the token (i.e., the tidytext format in R). The dataframe would look like this:

```py
        token  tag      lemma
1    everyone  PNI   everyone
2       seems  VVZ       seem
3          to  TO0         to
4          be  VBI         be
5     talking  VVG       talk
6       about  PRP      about
7         the  AT0        the
8   menopause  NN1  menopause
9          so  AV0         so
10         we  PNP         we
11    thought  VVD      think
12       that  CJT       that
13        you  PNP        you
14         'd  VHD       have
15     better  AV0       well
```

Note here that in order to save space in memory, the data type of each column is categorical (i.e., 'category' in Pandas).

Now let's say I want to add a column called 'context' where each cell contains the textual context around each token within a range of +- n. The resulting dataframe would look like this for n=1:

```py
        token  tag      lemma              context
1    everyone  PNI   everyone       everyone seems
2       seems  VVZ       seem    everyone seems to
3          to  TO0         to          seems to be
4          be  VBI         be        to be talking
5     talking  VVG       talk     be talking about
6       about  PRP      about    talking about the
7         the  AT0        the  about the menopause
8   menopause  NN1  menopause     the menopause so
9          so  AV0         so      menopause so we
10         we  PNP         we        so we thought
11    thought  VVD      think      we thought that
12       that  CJT       that     thought that you
13        you  PNP        you          that you 'd
14         'd  VHD       have        you 'd better
15     better  AV0       well           'd better
```

The code I've used to do this is:

```py
# set half-width of context window
n = 1

# add context column
df['context'] = df.shift(n).token.str.cat(
  others=[df.shift(-i).token for i in range(-n+1, n+1)], 
  sep=' ', 
  na_rep='')
```

Now this works well for any reasonable values of n so long as the dataframe itself has a relatively small number of rows (e.g., len(df) < ~1,000,000). However, when I scale this up to hundreds of millions of rows, processing takes several dozen minutes for small n sizes (~5) and chokes completely (MemoryError) on larger n sizes (e.g., n > ~10).

So my question is this: Does anyone have an alternate way of generating the context column that would work for large n sizes and/or dataframes?

Much obliged.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "PANDAS sliding window", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: Thanks Prune. I may have missed something with .rolling(), but as far as I can tell it returns an object of class Rolling which doesn't have implementations for any of the Pandas str functions. rolling() would be perfect if I could concatenate the string values of the token column, but that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: It's subclassed; I thought you could simply concatenate the `token` values.  Sorry for the false start.

Comment: Prune: thanks for the correction and no problem. I'll keep exploring rolling() just in case.